# How to let Jenkins always use the latest JDK?

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm aware of Jenkins' capability to automatically download the JDK from Oracle and install it. This seems to apply to specific version only, though. Is there a way to have Jenkins always install the latest JDK of a given release (e.g. the latest JDK 8, the latest JDK 9 preview) and also update the previously installed one in case there is an update?